# What city is this city scape?

Tags: identify-this, cities

I found this image of any amazing cityscape. Can anyone identify the city? It is so spectacular I wonder if it is even real. [image: The image shows a sprawling city surrounding a winding river with an incredible city center!]

Comment: Forgive me for my doubt, but could you include a source of where you found this image because it appears to be heavily edited if not completely computer generated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a computer-generated image that doesn't exist.

Comment: The river has no bridge, no boat, no wharf: this is unrealistic.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't appear to be real, but in these cases you really want Google's [Search By Image](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/images/searchbyimage.html).

That shows that it's almost certainly digital art created by [Mobius](http://www.eliteforever.co.uk/mobius.html), direct link to the image: http://www.eliteforever.co.uk/images/5MRVNb0.jpg

What's odd is that your version appears to have the flying craft and the signature removed. It looks like it's been modified into a wallpaper and hosted [here](http://www.wallsave.com/wallpaper/1366x768/autos-futuristas-fondos-de-pantalla-city-la-futura-metr-poli-futurista-r-o-d-464407.html). I don't know if that's been done with the authors permission or not.

Note -- I'm assuming the original I linked first really is the original and not the other way round (or they're both derivatives of some other image). More research would need to be done on that, but this isn't the right place.

Answer (score 4):

It's not real. You can see clearly in the image that several buildings are copied into it since they appear twice or more. This is a CG (computer graphics) [wallpaper](http://www.wallsave.com/wallpaper/1366x768/autos-futuristas-fondos-de-pantalla-city-la-futura-metr-poli-futurista-r-o-d-464407.html) of a fictional futuristic city.

Comment: Not that I disagree with the conclusion,but real cities do also have "copied" buildings. It's cheap to use the same architecture and plans repeatedly.

Comment: For low-rise housing, sure, but not for skyscrapers, unless they're part of the same complex (Petronas Towers etc).

Comment: I agree with @jpatokal. The left-most tall building appears 4 times almost identical in the central area of the city.